# Disable onTouch when using onClick

Tags: android, accessibility, text-to-speech

I am creating an Android application for visually impaired and am using a menu of buttons.

When a user slides his fingers on the screen the application reads the button's captions. This is accomplished using onTouch events. When a user clicks a button, an action happens (change activity, or any other action) which is accompanied by a speech feedback. This is accomplished using onClick events.

The problem is that when clicking a button both events fire (onTouch and onClick) and the TTS begins to read the onTouch message, stops after half a second and starts the new message which was declared in the onClick event. How can I disable the firing of the onTouch when invoking onClick. I understand the problem because onTouch always precedes onClick, but I have no idea for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid click event apply the tap event.

First create gesture class.

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then create a **GestureDetector gestureDetector;** object and

```
gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(myContext, new MyGestureDetector());
```

Then register with on touch event.

```
view.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

override the onTouch Method like this.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        Button b=(Button) view;
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
```

Here do some task on Single tap and Double Tap.

Comment: But I don't use double tap. I use ontouch to move over the screen and receive audio feedback on the things shown on the screen and onclick to activate elements shown on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public final OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

or

`object.setOnTouchListener(null);`

Comment: I don't understand how this answers my question. This only disables the onTouch, Whereas I need both of them.